# Compound numeral adjectives

Tags: adjectives, numerals

I wonder about the "and in compounds numeral adjectives: should I say "a five-hundred-AND-forty-six-metre-tall/high tower" or should I remove the AND? Do I correctly place the hyphens?

Comment: Say or write? I would write "a 546 metre high tower." If speaking, I would include the **and**.

Comment: Say and write in full letters to show the hyphens

Comment: The only difference in **saying** would be the inclusion of **and** (which I, but not everyone, would). I would not spell out the number in writing.

Comment: I understand, but if you ever had to spell them out, how would you put it?

Comment: I would only spell small/short numbers, but not always. For example "there are four 12 metre high towers" removes confusion between quantity and height.

Comment: ...oh, but if I *had* to, I would omit the **hyphens** but include the **and**.

Comment: This will be "office specific." If it's your personal writing, you pick a style and stay with it. If it's in collaboration with others, or for an editor, check the style guide.  Personally I would not use the hyphens, and would use the and.